# Jenkins 2.60.2 returns "CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid" when running Gradle Task

Tags: java, jenkins, gradle

I just installed Jenkins 2.60.2 using Windows Installer and then configure it to run my Gradle Task.

My build.gradle is located in C:\Workspace\SSD\build.gradle , so I put the path in Jenkins's configuration page, field "Root Build script :" `C:\Workspace\SSD\build.gradle`

When I click "Build Now" , Jenkins returns

```
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Testing
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[build.gradle] $ cmd.exe /C "gradle.bat gradle clean test -PSSD && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
The directory name is invalid
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd.exe" (in directory "C:\Workspace\SSD\build.gradle"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:850)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.join(Launcher.java:395)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.performTask(Gradle.java:330)
    at hudson.plugins.gradle.Gradle.perform(Gradle.java:221)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:735)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:490)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1735)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 17 more
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I changed the field "Root Build script" to `C:\\Workspace\\SSD\\build.gradle` , still doesn't work.

When I build my codes using gradle (without Jenkins), it works fine.

Any clue maybe?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation at https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gradle+Plugin, and from the error it gives you, it expects the folder of the build script in that configuration option, not the full path to the script itself. Change it to `C:\Workspace\SSD` and I expect it will work.

Comment: That works. Thanks.  I also found a mistake, in task field , we don't need to put `gradle` , just directly the argument such as `clean build` for example.